# Geoshow in Matlab - facecolor changes when printing to tiff file

Tags: image, matlab, matlab-figure, save-image

My figure is a map of the USA. I would like all states' `facecolor` to be white unless specified:

```
ax = usamap('conus');
states = shaperead('usastatelo', 'UseGeoCoords', true,'Selector',{@(name) ~any(strcmp(name,{'Alaska','Hawaii'})), 'Name'});
faceColors = makesymbolspec('Polygon', {'Name','Washington','FaceColor','red'}, {'Name','Alabama','FaceColor','red'});
geoshow(ax, states, 'DisplayType', 'polygon', 'SymbolSpec', faceColors,'DefaultFaceColor','w','DefaultEdgeColor','black')
framem off; gridm off; mlabel off; plabel off
```

But when I print it using:

```
print -r600 -dtiff MyMap.tif
```

and open the figure, some of the states' `facecolor` on the east are black.

Why is this and how can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: I cannot reconstruct your problem. Which version do you use? on what system?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your problem using Matlab 2016a

Comment: OK thanks @Sardar_Usama

Comment: @EBH 2015b on a mac - I will update to 2016 and see if that helps

Comment: I use 2016a too, on windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bug does not exist in **MATLAB 2016a**. But I tried your code in **MATLAB 2015a** and I got the following *.tif* file as output (which is also described by you in the question):

[image]

There is a workaround to make this right. Before using `print` command, write the following line:

```
set(gcf, 'color', 'w', 'InvertHardCopy', 'off');
```

which gives the desired *.tif* output file as shown below:

[image: required output]

Answer (score 1):

I haven't really figured out why but when I set the `DefaultFaceColor` to almost white, it works...

```
'DefaultFaceColor',[1.000 0.9792 0.9792]
```